# Где хранить исходные файлы / задания проекта?

Tags: файловая-система, дерево, проект

Интересует правильное именование папок или файловой структуры (если такая существует).

В самом начале разработки мне передают файлы для верстки, ТЗ и т.д.
Где правильно хранить исходные файлы проекта?
Например, такие как:

- design.psd
- design.jpg
- ТЗ.doc

и т.п.

Естественно, файлов может быть больше / меньше и их названия могу варьироваться.
Основной смысл заключается в правильности их размещения в проекте или вне проекта.

*Push-ить ли их в репозиторий вместе с исходными кодами или нет?*

Изначальная файловая структура была следующей:

> .git
>   .idea - *именно сюда я и складывал изначальные файлы, пока не прочитал, что это директория для IDE, в связи с чем и возник данный вопрос.*
>   src
>   package.json
>   ...

Answer (score 4):

*Ваш вопрос:*

> Интересует правильное именование папок или файловой структуры (если такая существует).

*Ответ:*
Могу лишь поделится личным опытом структурирования файлов на фронтенде. На вопрос, как правильно, который я задал с десятку знакомых (когда у меня он встал на повестке дня), мне отвечали по разному, но общая параллель была. В основном это две основные папки (названия каждый называл разные, но суть одна и та же) + папки `node_modules, bower_components`. Эта структура обычного фронтенд проекта (хотя, как написал выше, все это опционально). 
 Получается структура вроде этой:

> |-/build
>   |-/node_modules
>   |-/bower_components
>   |-/src
>   |--- doc/
>   |--- fonts/
>   |--- img/
>   |--- scripts/
>   |--- style/
>   |--- vendors/
>   |--- template/
>   |--- index.html
>   |- .gitignore
>   |- gulpfile.js
>   |- package.json
>   |- bower.json
>   |- README.md

`/built` - папка продакшена (многие ее именуют `/dist`).
`/src` - папка исходников (многие ее именуют `/app`).

Также еще может быть отдельная папка для тасков. Папка `/src` тоже может структурироватся иначе, не все прям в нее на кучу (все зависит от объема), а подразделять ее на папки типа: `/assets`,`/template` и т.д.

*Ваш вопрос:*

> В самом начале разработки мне передают файлы для верстки, ТЗ и т.д.
>   Где правильно хранить исходные файлы проекта?

*Ответ:*
Я храню в `/template`, мне кажется это логичным. Также рекомендую нормально структурировать `.gitignore` - комментируйте, что там откуда и куда, вам же легче будет.

*Ваш вопрос:*

> Push-ить ли их в репозиторий вместе с исходными кодами или нет?

*Ответ:*
Я не делаю для них `push`, нет необходимости.

Answer (score 3):

Нашел ответы по запросу:

> структура проектной папки

И как осознание, что единой структуры не существует и под каждый проект своя структура.

Решил взять на вооружение некоторые советы отсюда:
https://habrahabr.ru/post/319296/

Создал рядом с папкой

> .git

папку

> .incoming

В которой уже все структурирую в зависимости от проекта.